# ActiveRecord: group by count of associated has_many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given that a User has many properties:

```
class User
  has_many :properties
end
```

I want a report that would first calculate how many properties each user has, and then group the users that have the same number of properties together, counting them.

I cannot use a counter cache on the User model for reasons that are out of scope of the question (the query merges a dynamic scope of Properties).

To keep it simple, so far we have this:

```
`User.joins(:properties).group('users.email')
     .order('COUNT(properties.id) DESC').count`
```

This returns a hash like this:

```
{
  "email1@gmail.com"=>209,
  "email2@gmail.com"=>160,
  "email3@gmail.com"=>160
}
```

My goal is, based on the previous example hash, end up with a hash like this:

```
{
  209 => 1,
  160 => 2
}
```

Because we had 1 user with 209 properties and 2 users with 160 properties.

I already achieved the result using ruby's `.group_by`, but the goal is to achieve it using ActiveRecord / SQL only. I don't mind having to run raw SQL if that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need help on this. But if other users stumble on this, hope it helps them.

`User.joins(:properties).group('users.id')
     .order('COUNT(properties.id) DESC').count`